# I cannot pass variables from Slurm script to Bash script

Tags: bash, arguments, slurm

Somehow I fail to pass variables from a Slurm job script to Bash. I thought it had worked previously and I cannot find the error.

The Slurm script runs is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH -A node
... (MORE SLURM OPTIONS)

HABITAT=trocken
PRJDIR=/home/poppman/rca/prj
PATCHDIR=/home/poppman/rca/dat/pat
RESDIR=/home/poppman/rca/dat/res
GRAPHAB=/home/poppman/rca/opt/graphab-2.8.jar

MAXEUC=1500
MAXRES=250000

METRIC=PC

srun /home/poppman/rca/base_graphs_p.sh -p $PROJNAME -t $HABITAT -e $MAXEUC -r $MAXRES -m $METRIC -i ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} -d "false"
```

The bash script it runs starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while getopts p:t:e:r:m:i:d: options
do
  case "${options}" in
    p) PROJNAME=${OPTARG} ;;
    t) HABITAT=${OPTARG} ;;
    e) MAXEUC=${OPTARG} ;;
    r) MAXRES=${OPTARG} ;;
    m) METRIC=${OPTARG} ;;
    i) JOBID=${OPTARG} ;;
    d) EUCLID=${OPTARG} ;;
  esac
done
```

but somehow the variables contain no values. I also tried quoting `":p:t:e:r:m:i:d:"` and other small changes, but the variables remain empty. What's the issue here?

Comment: I don't know `slurm`, but my intuitive approach would be to define those variables as **environment** variable, and then access them directly instead of fiddling with `getopts`. Of course this implies that slurm runs your bash script as child process, and does not deliberately empty the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just found out I didn't assign the first variable that is to be passed as a parameter. Somehow this cause the entire thing to fail.